# SQL Partition Rank

Tags: sql, teradata, rank, partition

I am trying to get a unique license per year by ID Number that follows a pattern. I have tried using rank and partition but having some trouble getting the final output as some licenses have different start and end dates before and after each other. The data right now looks like:[image]

Ideally, I want the final output to be:
[image]

Comment: the above example is for one ID. I have over one million which is why this is difficult for me. Thanks

Comment: `by ID Number that follows a pattern.` Which pattern ? Could you please explain more ? I can't see any pattern in this table.

Comment: I am trying to the license that shows up frequently in the following years.

Comment: Is there one row per year/License? And you want those licenses which exist in multiple years? Do you want those where there's a value greater 1 in `Reneval` column?

Comment: @dnoeth exactly. renewal shouldn't really matter. if we look at the above example, the renewal should be sequential once done correctly. 0...1...2...etc. for 2015, 2016, 2017, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why do the staggered start/end dates matter?  As long as you can determine which year a record belongs to, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM <Table_Name>
QUALIFY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID_Number, Year ORDER BY <Some_Expression>) = 1
```

This will create a partition (group) per each (ID/Year) combination, which you can then process however you want.  Use `<Some_Expression>` to order the rows so that the row with the data you want to display gets sorted at the top.  The RANK = 1 will return only this "top" row per group.

Is that along the lines of what you're looking for?

Comment: this wouldn't get the final output unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from mytable
qualify max(year) over (partiton by license)     -- example:
      - min(year) over (partiton by license)     -- 2017 - 2015 = 2
      = count(*)  over (partiton by license) - 1 -- three rows -1 = 2 
    and count(*)  over (partiton by license) > 1
```

There's more than one year and those years are consecutive.

Comment: hmmm...doesn't seem to work. was getting no output from that query. thank you though

Comment: Of course, my logic is wrong, you count three years between 2015 and 2017, but 2017-2015 returns two. Fixed it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just gotta understand the logic for my sake. However, I am not getting any records for 2014. Is there a way to edit this logic to get a (random or first) record for 2014 as well? I only get threes worth (2015-2017).

Comment: @ali.hash2: If there's a row for the same license in 2014, too, it will be returned. Otherwise you need to add more example data to your question...